# Can't get decimals to display in text field for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdecimal

Confused Rails 3 newbie. My model has a purchase_price attribute defined like this:

```
t.decimal :purchase_price, :precision => 12, :scale => 2, :default => 0.00
```

My goal is to have a simple Rails 3 app where I can view and edit this value. In my model, I defined a custom getter to force 2 decimal places to always exist.

```
def purchase_price
  sprintf( "%.2f",attributes['purchase_price'])
end
```

This works correctly from the console and when I display the show page. On the edit page I have a text field to edit this value. My problem is that if this value is saved as '123.00' the value is displayed as '123.0'.

Questions:

1. Why is my custom getter not getting called?
2. Why is this displayed with 1 decimal and not 2 decimals?

**Update**

1. Decimal value as stored in MySQL: 100.20
2. Value returned from console: 100.20
3. Value displayed in text field: 100.2
4. Value returned via Firebug: "100.2"
5. The text field length is not an issue.
6. If the value in the db is 100.21, it is displayed correctly as 100.21

Comment: in addiion to what mu said, try inspecting the textfield using firebug, does it still say 123.0? maybe it's just not showing every character(textfield is too short)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
f.text_field :purchase_price, :value=>number_to_currency(f.object.purchase_price, :unit=>'')
```

That should convert the number to a currency (with two decimal places) and the `:unit=>''` will exclude the "$".

And I'd recommend removing your custom `purchase_price` method and using the `number_to_currency` helper where needed instead. Overriding the `purchase_price` accessor isn't a bad idea but it could confuse some things that might be expecting a number rather than a string.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. I was unaware of the format you provided.